# Laravel Eloquent: Sort table by sum count of two tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by

I have a products, comments and child comments table.

Products.php mode

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Comment', 'commentable')->orderBy('id');
}
```

Comment.php model

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ChildComment');
}
```

My goal is now to execute a eloquent query which returns me the products table but ordered by the `comments_count` + `child_comments_count`.

At the moment this is how I get my `totalCommentsCount` attribute. I know it's not perfect but I don't know how do to this better... Also I cannot order the eloquent query by this attribute because at this point the query has already been executed:

```
public function getCommentsAndChildrenCountAttribute(){
    $comments = $this->comments()->with('children')->withCount('children')->get();

    $count = 0;
    foreach($comments as $comment){
        $count += $comment->children_count + 1;
    }

    return $count;
}
```

Does anybody has an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code does the job ?

```
Product::withCount([
    'comments as count_comments', 
    'comments.children as comments_count_children'
])->orderByRaw('count_comments + comments_count_children desc')->get();
```